# Model formula for two-way interactions between one set of variables and another

Tags: r, r-model-formula

I would like to specify all two-way interactions between a set of variables (e.g., `a`, `b`, and `c`) and one other (e.g., `x`). Is there a more efficient way to write the following formula?

```cpp
Y ~ a*x + b*x + c*x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following does the trick:

```cpp
Y ~ (a + b + c)*x
```